# Fetching new Google+ profile picture in Android

Tags: android, google-plus

In my app the user can login using his/her Google+ account.
Amongst other things, we fetch the user's profile picture.

What we have found is that if the user changes his picture on the web then this change is not reflected on the phone. I guess that this is because logging out of our app is not logging out of Google and so no refresh is done.

Is there any way to fetch the latest picture. I'd rather avoid "work-arounds" that may not work in the future.

Answer (score 0):

So we will assume we have a login button that starts a method that first authenticates us and of course give us the require data`login.setOnClickListener(view -> 
                syncGoogleAccount());`

and the method that will log us in, we will first loop through our apps for our email address using this method:

```
public String findGmailAccount() {

    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
    Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();

    if (accounts.length > 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < accounts.length; j++) {
            Account account = accounts[j];
            if (account.type != null && account.type.equals("com.google")) {

                String email = account.name;
                return email;

            } else

            {

                return null;

            }
        }
    }


    return null;
}


 public void syncGoogleAccount() {

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        String accountarrs = findGmailAccount();
        if (accountarrs != null) {
            //you can set here account for login
            getTask(register.this, accountarrs, SCOPE).execute();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Google Account Sync!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Network Service!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

it is important to check for connectivity before doing any network operations, so we first check for connectivity.

```
 public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        Log.e("Network Testing", "***Available***");
        return true;
    }
    Log.e("Network Testing", "***Not Available***");
    return false;
}
```

and then if we are logged in we call our information getter method that gets our information with img url included

```
    public static  void getUserInformationFromAccount() {
    try {
        System.out.println("On Home Page***\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                + AbstractGetNameTask.GOOGLE_USER_DATA);
        JSONObject profileData = new JSONObject(
                AbstractGetNameTask.GOOGLE_USER_DATA);

        if (profileData.has("picture")) {
            String userImageUrl = profileData.getString("picture");
            new GetImageFromUrl().execute(userImageUrl);
        }

        if (profileData.has("name")) {
            myname = profileData.getString("name");
            userDetails.setName(myname);


        }
        if (profileData.has("gender")) {
            gender = profileData.getString("gender");

        }
        if (profileData.has("birthday")) {
             birthday = profileData.getString("birthday");

        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

our image link async which downloads our images/user profile images

```
 public static class GetImageFromUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap map = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            map = downloadImage(url);
        }
        return map;
    }

    // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        profilepic.setImageBitmap(result);
        CommonMethods.saveUserImageToSd(result, Constant.GOOGLE_IMAGE, Constant.DISPLAY_IMAGE);
    }

    // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the same profile picture could be **stored cache of image**. Try to remove cache from your image loading library that you are using. I use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library and it has option of removing cache.

Try this may be this could help you in some way.

May I know which library you are using for Image loading ?

EDIT:

If you want to get Profile Pic then hit on URL i.e
**Request URL**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/10343557736...774874?fields=image&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You just have to pass UserId and your API Key. After that you will get Response like.

```
{
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-xIeb3BMYFMU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAhU/gQOwkKFA2OE/photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "isDefault": false
 }
}
```

You can change the size according to your need like `sz=150`

When you will use that URL make sure that cache is off from image loading library. After that whenever you will fetch user image it will reflect latest profile image not the previous image that stored in cache.

Comment: I am directly downloading the image using the URL supplied by Google+ when connecting.

Comment: I made some changes in my answer.Go through that, I hope it will help you.